# Problems setting environment variables for Intel C++ Composer "GCC not found"

Tags: c++, variables, gcc, intel, environment

I just installed Intel® C++ Composer XE 2013 SP1 for Linux on a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 and was following the Getting Started html file to set environment variables. I try to complete the following:

"Open a terminal session.
Run the compiler environment script compilervars.sh:
source /bin/compilervars.sh 
where  is the directory structure containing the compiler /bin directory, and  is one of the following architecture arguments:
intel64: Compilers and libraries for Intel® 64 architectures only
ia32: Compilers and libraries for IA-32 architectures only
Note The default path for  is /opt/intel/."

When i execute the command "sudo ./compilervars.sh intel64"

I get "WARNING: 'gcc' was not found
./compilervars.sh: 39: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/ipp/bin/ippvars.sh: [[: not found"

I then install gcc using the command "sudo apt-get install build-essential" then tried executing the above again and got the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the standard installation dir = "/opt/intel", IPP 8.1 SP1.3.174 version installed on Debian 7.5 Wheezy:

```
> cd /opt/intel/bin
> ./compilervars.sh intel64
./compilervars.sh: 40: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/ipp/bin/ippvars.sh: [[: not found
```

This mean: *error executing compilervars.sh, in line 40 of /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/ipp/bin/ippvars.sh*

**BRIEF EXPLANATION:** (If you want to go direclty to solution, jump to "SOLUTION" section)

Let's see that script

```
> ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 jun  8 04:06 compilervars.csh -> ../composerxe/bin/compilervars.csh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 jun  8 04:06 compilervars.sh -> ../composerxe/bin/compilervars.sh
```

compilersvars.sh points to ../composerxe/bin/compilervars.sh... Let's see that folder:

```
> ls -l ../composerxe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 jun  8 04:06 ../composerxe -> composer_xe_2013_sp1
```

Oh my, another link! so "../composerxe/bin/compilervars.sh" is "/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/bin/compilervars.sh".

> gedit ./compilervars.sh

In that script, **PROD_DIR=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1** tell us what version of compiler is using. The script asks for existence of some *.sh files, and if that's the case, executes them. That's the case of /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/ipp/bin/ippvars.sh.

**SOLUTION:**

```
> gedit /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/ipp/bin/ippvars.sh
```

and go to line 40:

```
   if [[ "$1" != "ia32" && "$1" != "intel64" && "$1" != "ia32_intel64" ]]; then
```

replace this line by:

```
   if [ "$1" != "ia32" ] && [ "$1" != "intel64" ] && [ "$1" != "ia32_intel64" ]; then
```

Save and reexecute script:

```
> ./compilervars.sh intel64
>
```

Now executed without complains.

Comment: Marvelous job !!!   
its just checking for ia32 and not for option intel64/ia_intel64, resulting to error like intel64/ia_intel64 not supporting, which is wrong.   I think you should report it to intel.   I think, `[[ "$1" != "ia32"] && ["$1" != "intel64"] && ["$1" != "ia32_intel64" ]]` should also do.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar error with composer_xe_2015 (Debian 7.6):

```
$ sudo ./compilervars.sh intel64 
./compilervars.sh: 13: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015/ipp/bin/ippvars.sh: [[: not found
```

As [bull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2531713/bull) points out, the issue involves symlinks. Although the scripts can be changed, an easier solution seems to be to just omit the `./` from the command:

```
$ sudo bash compilervars.sh intel64
```

Success!

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue. Turned out one of the "if" checks script does was passing but there was something wrong with what the loop was trying to do. So you might wanna check which "if" block in compilervars.sh gives that error.

In my case it was `"if [ -e $PROD_DIR/tbb/bin/tbbvars.sh ]"`. The script was there but rest of the tbb stuff was not.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit of a newbie... Is the if statement checking for something I am missing in thT directory? Or is there something wrong with the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with tbbvars.sh as well.  For some reason no user group had permissions to execute the script, so I just chmod 755 tbbvars.sh and then the script executes w/o complaining.  I also have this [[: not found issue with the ippvars.sh so I try to get this to work next..

Ok for the ippvars.sh script replace line 39 w/ this exactly (spacing is  important)

```
if [ "$1" != "ia32" ] && [ "$1" != "intel64" ];   then
```

I've read others say is an issue w/ shell not having all capabilities of bash, not sure but this fix again made it work at least w/o the script making any complaints

Answer (score 0):

Today I cam across this error when trying to install Intel® C++ Composer XE 2013 SP1 for Linux. Changing the shebang from #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash in the compilevars.sh script did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

i run xubuntu 12.04 64bit.

when i execute `/opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh` i get the error

> ./compilervars.sh: 40:
>   /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/ipp/bin/ippvars.sh: [[: not found"

I have checked the previous solutions and none of the above worked well.

Finally i tried 
source `/opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh` without changing anything and bang.

i had icc in my path. 
then 
edit .bashrc and added the following line at the end
source `/opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh` intel64